# How would I go about calling a function from a preprocessor in C++?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have multiple classes. I want to store them all in a map array.

```
std::map<std::string, ClassMaker*> lookupTable;
```

I think it would be pretty inefficient if I do something similar to

```
void addClass(std::string className, ClassMaker* const classMaker);
addClass("Class1", new Class1());
addClass("Class2", new Class2());
```

and so on.

I was curious if there was some way I could go about doing this with preprocessors, something in the terms of

```
#DEFINE_CLASS(Class) 

DEFINE_CLASS(Class1)
```

and it will store the class in a map so I can access it later.

Comment: Look up "X macro".  Bear in mind that preprocessor hackery is pretty strongly discouraged in C++ - for quite a few good reasons.  You'd be better off looking up techniques based on design patterns - both in terms of maintainability and in terms of the "ick" factor from self-respecting C++ developers of using macro hackery in C++.

Comment: BTW, `REGISTER_CLASS` seems better naming than `DEFINE_CLASS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
#define DEFINE_CLASS(className) addClass(#className, new className())

DEFINE_CLASS(Class1);
DEFINE_CLASS(Class2);
// ...
```

Comment: But what if both class1 and class2 are different? How can I define that in the preprocessor?

Comment: Preprocessor wont care. Think of it as a simple text replacer.

Comment: @Kurieita Obviously they're different. If they were the same what would be the point of doing it?